# Saving User-Chosen Stylesheet via jQuery and Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

**Edit: I figured it out.** I'm a complete numpty and didn't test putting the switcher code at the top of my other scripts. As soon as I did that, I fixed it, and it works perfectly.

Old post below.

---

I want to be able to have my users select a stylesheet via button or link, and have the browser remember that. I'm not great with jQuery, but I know generally enough to follow tutorials and reverse-engineer, to a point.

I have been attempting to use [this plugin](http://electrokami.com/coding/jquery-style-sheet-switcher-with-preview/), but it's not playing nicely with my existing code. There are a couple of things that could be causing the issue, <strike>but I think the most likely culprit is the different versions of jQuery that are used. Using just the 1.4.4 breaks some of the core functionality (the ability to reset the checkbox state), and using just the 1.11.2 means that the plugin doesn't work at all. I've no idea how to resolve this, nor even what to google.</strike>

**After further testing**, when using the demo's index.html, I can use just the 1.11 library without breaking functionality. But when using *my* index.html, it doesn't function at all. So that's probably not the issue.

The demo HTML is viewable online, and [here is a pastebin of my full index.html](http://pastebin.com/ge4J1EtA). Obligatory plea for mercy regarding my subpar coding skills.

---

Here's the demo header:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme" href="css/theme1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.4">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.style-switcher.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').styleSwitcher();
});
</script>
```

And here's my header:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/classic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus+SC|Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://starbuckguild.com/ore/favicon.png">

<script>
//Add functionality for hiding perm nodes that may be silver or iron
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=both]").not(".textbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("input[name=both]").prop('checked', true)
        $("input[name=both]").parent(".container").addClass("visited_node");
        $("input[name=both]").parent(".container").hide(500);
        }
    else $(this).parent(".container").removeClass("visited_node")
    });

    $("input[name=both2]").not(".textbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("input[name=both2]").prop('checked', true)
        $("input[name=both2]").parent(".container").addClass("visited_node");
        $("input[name=both2]").parent(".container").hide(500);
        }
    else $(this).parent(".container").removeClass("visited_node")
    });

    $("input[name=both3]").not(".textbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("input[name=both3]").prop('checked', true)
        $("input[name=both3]").parent(".container").addClass("visited_node");
        $("input[name=both3]").parent(".container").hide(500);
        }
    else $(this).parent(".container").removeClass("visited_node")
    });

//Mark node as visited.
    $("input").not(".textbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent(".container").addClass("visited_node");
        $(this).parent(".container").hide(500);
        }
    else $(this).parent(".container").removeClass("visited_node")
    });

//Show visited nodes
    $("#showall").click(function () {
        $(".visited_node").show();
    });

//Hide visited nodes
    $("#hideall").click(function () {
        $(".visited_node").hide();
    });

//Hide all nodes with list price less than 1s
    $("#good").click(function () {
    $("input[name=bad]").parent(".container").addClass("visited_node");
    $("input[name=bad]").parent(".container").hide();
    });

//Add short route function
    $("#short").click(function () {
    $("input").parent(".container").addClass("visited_node");
    $("input").parent(".container").hide();
    $("input[name=1hr]").parent(".container").removeClass("visited_node");
    $("input[name=1hr]").parent(".container").show();
    });

//Prompt user to reset all nodes
    $("#uncheckall").click(function () {
    $(".button").show();
    $(this).hide();
    });

//Actually reset all nodes if user is sure
    $("#imsure").click(function () {
    $(".visited_node").show();
    $("input").not(".textbox").prop("checked", false);
    $(".visited_node").removeClass("visited_node");
    $(".button").show();
    $(this).hide();
    });

//Hide or show nodes by type
    $("#nav a").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.split('_');
    if ($(this).is(".off")){
        $("#menu #menu_" + id[1]).show();
    }
    else {
        $("#menu #menu_" + id[1]).hide();
    }
        $(this).toggleClass("off");
    });

//Show map to nodes when clicked
        var option = 'blank';
        var url = window.location.href;
        option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
        showDiv(option);
    });
    function showDiv(option) {
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $('#' + option).show();
        $('#blank').hide();
    }
```

The plugin also requires

```
<div id="header">
   <a href="javascript: void(0)" title="switch styling" id="theme1">Default</a>
   <a href="javascript: void(0)" title="switch styling" id="theme2">Darkness</a> 
   <a href="javascript: void(0)" title="switch styling" id="theme3">Colorful</a>
</div>
```

to be placed in the body of the page. I've just been putting it inside my navigation div at the top of the page, but perhaps I'm making a mistake there as well/instead.

As an aside, I note that the local machine version of the demo's index.html does not save the stylesheet preferences, whereas the web version does - I assume this is normal behaviour? **Edit: It is. It works fine when uploaded.**

Comment: when you say using just jQuery1.11 breaks.... is that making sure that jQuery 1.11 loads before the plugin? That order is important. jQuery library has to load before any code dependent on it. Source of the switcher plugin doesn't seem to have anything in it that should break

Comment: I have been placing the 1.11 library on the line above the switcher, yes.

Comment: That wasn't precisely issue, but it did make me check the order of my scripts, which led me to the solution. Thank you very much for your help!